# Script that saves a series of pages then tries to combine them but only combines one?

Tags: ruby, open-uri

Here's my code..

```
require "open-uri"

base_url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki"

(1..5).each do |x|
  # sets up the url
  full_url = base_url + "/" + x.to_s
  # reads the url
  read_page = open(full_url).read
  # saves the contents to a file and closes it
  local_file = "my_copy_of-" + x.to_s + ".html"
  file = open(local_file,"w")
  file.write(read_page)
  file.close

  # open a file to store all entrys in

  combined_numbers = open("numbers.html", "w")

  entrys = open(local_file, "r")

  combined_numbers.write(entrys.read)

  entrys.close
  combined_numbers.close

end
```

As you can see. It basically scrapes the contents of the wikipedia articles 1 through 5 and then attempts to combine them nto a single file called numbers.html.

It does the first bit right. But when it gets to the second. It only seem's to write in the contents of the fifth article in the loop.

I can't see where im going wrong though. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chose the wrong [mode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html) when opening your summary file. **"w" overwrites existing files** while **"a" appends to existing files**.

So use this to get your code working:

```
combined_numbers = open("numbers.html", "a")
```

Otherwise with each pass of the loop the file contents of *numbers.html* are overwritten with the current article.

---

Besides I think you should use the contents in `read_page` to write to `numbers.html` instead of reading them back in from your freshly written file:

```
require "open-uri"

(1..5).each do |x|
  # set up and read url
  url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/#{x.to_s}"
  article = open(url).read

  # saves current article to a file
  # (only possible with 1.9.x use open too if on 1.8.x)
  IO.write("my_copy_of-#{x.to_s}.html", article)

  # add current article to summary file
  open("numbers.html", "a") do |f|
    f.write(article)
  end
end
```